# Accessing Saved Pickle Model in github

Tags: python, machine-learning, github, pickle, github-pages

So I saved my trained machine learning model as pickle in github, but I can't find a way  to access it yet? Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to get it using a get call:

```py
import joblib
from io import BytesIO

import requests # or https

# e.g. a file call stopwords saved by joblib
# https://github.com/Proteusiq/hisia/v1.0.1/hisia/models/data/stops.pkl

# change github.com to raw.githubusercontent.com

URI = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Proteusiq/hisia/v1.0.1/hisia/models/data/stops.pkl"
STOPWORDS = joblib.load(BytesIO(requests.get(URI).content))
```

The idea is to request the file and read it as bytes.

❗️Unpickling file is dangerous. make sure you are sure of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the github repository it's in and run pickle.load to load the pickle file.

Comment: It means i have to access it locally from my computer right? is there any way i can access it online?

Comment: I don’t think there is a way.

Comment: There is using requests or httpx ☺️